# centre images with my text on side

Tags: html, css

How do I get my text to be in the middle of my image?

```
          |image1| |Image2|
text blah |  X   | |  x   |
          |  X   | |  x   |
```

Code:

```
<p style="color:white;">
    &copy;<% = year(now())%> company.CoZa | 
    <a href="http://www.company.com">House</a> powered by 
    <a href="http://www.company2.net">Company</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a id="facebook" href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"</a>
    <a id="youtube" href="#"><img src="images/youtube.png"</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Much easier if everything wasn't in one paragraph. Why is it that way and can you change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6pvb/)**</kbd>

You should done very easily: apply the **`vertical-align`** CSS to the image.

#### CSS

```
img{
    vertical-align:middle; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add:

```
img{    
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7YsU6/)

Or, if you have multiple images displayed vertically- you can use CSS tables

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7YsU6/1/)

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='cell'>text text text</div>
    <div class='cell'>
        <img src='http://developers.blog.box.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/thumbnail-sample.png' />
        <br />
        <img src='http://developers.blog.box.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/thumbnail-sample.png' />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using `vertical-align: middle`

HTML:

```
<p>
    Text <img src="img.png" />
</p>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KSWef/2/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the HTML markup is not proper,

1) You have not closed the image tags properly.

2) The `<a>` tag at the end is not closed properly.

3) Inline css is evil while managing code (separation of concerns is important)

**Now regarding the solution:**

```
  p {
  display : table;
}

p span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
span .image  {
  display: table;
}
```

**HTML** :

```
    <p>

  <span>&copy;<% = year(now())%> company.CoZa | <a href="http://www.company.com">House</a> powered by <a href="http://www.company2.net">Company</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   </span>
 <span> <a id="facebook" class="image" href="#"><img src="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/images-photo.jpg" style="width: 200px;"></a>
  <a href="#" class="image" ><img src="http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/images-photo.jpg" style="width: 200px;"></span>
   </p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your image and your text are in the same element, set `line-height: XXpx;` of your text to be qual to the height of your image.

Comment: You should provide some code sample to illustrate what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

To be more simple you can use a table:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3" >text </th>
    <th >image</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>image</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>image</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```